# communication with channels of type array

Tags: go, channel

I'm trying using a simple model here to test my understanding of go channels. in the small snippet below I try to use 2 processes of a fake news feed that append several headlines to a local array then pass that to the array string channel. in main I pass these array back to a different process for printing.

**Edit:** I forgot to mention the problem.. my issue is that I keep getting 'index out of boundary' exception and I'm unable to compile the code.

Now I tried this same code with plain string variables and it works.

string array code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    /* initialization and assignment of channels */
    c := make(chan []string)
    p := make(chan []string)

    /* Pass created channels to Goroutines */
    go Feeder1(p)
    go Feeder2(p)
    go Consumer(c)

    for {
        select {
        case produced := <-p:
            c <- produced
        /*case <-time.After(6 * time.Second):
        return*/
        default:
            fmt.Printf("\n --- We timed out! --- \n")
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

        }
    }
}

func Feeder2(w chan []string) {

    headlines := []string{
        "BBC: Speedboat victim 'doted on family'\n",
        "BBC: Syria rebel sarin claim downplayed\n",
        "BBC: German 'ex-Auschwitz guard' arrested\n",
        "BBC: Armless artist 'denied entry' to UK\n",
        "BBC: Bangladesh protest clashes kill 27\n",
        "BBC: Ex-Italian PM Giulio Andreotti dies\n"}

    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        selection := []string{}
        for s := 0; s <= 3; s++ {
            selection[s] = headlines[randInt(0, len(headlines))]
        }
        w <- selection
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}

func Feeder1(w chan []string) {

    headlines := []string{
        "SKY: Deadly Virus Can 'Spread Between People'\n",
        "SKY: Ariel Castro's Brothers Brand Him 'A Monster'\n",
        "SKY: Astronaut Ends Space Mission With Bowie Song\n",
        "SKY: Chinese Artist Films Violent Street Brawl\n",
        "SKY: May Washout: Fortnight's Rainfall In One Day\n",
        "SKY: Mother's Day Shooting: CCTV Shows Suspect\n"}

    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        selection := []string{}
        for q := 0; q <= 3; q++ {
            selection[q] = headlines[randInt(0, len(headlines))]
        }
        w <- selection
        //randomTimeValue := randInt(5, 6)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}

func Consumer(n chan []string) {

    for {
        v := <-n
        for _, x := range v {
            fmt.Printf("Headline:\t%s", x)
        }
    }
}

func randInt(min int, max int) int {
    return min + rand.Intn(max-min)
}
```

The previously running version of the code (no arrays here):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    /* initialization and assignment of channels */
    c := make(chan string)
    p := make(chan string)

    /* Pass created channels to Goroutines */
    go Feeder1(p)
    go Feeder2(p)
    go Consumer(c)

    for {
        select {

        case produced := <-p:
            c <- produced
        /*case <-time.After(6 * time.Second):
        return*/
        default:
            fmt.Printf("\n --- We timed out! --- \n")
            time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

        }
    }
}

func Feeder2(w chan string) {
    headlines := []string{
        "BBC: Speedboat victim 'doted on family'\n",
        "BBC: Syria rebel sarin claim downplayed\n",
        "BBC: German 'ex-Auschwitz guard' arrested\n",
        "BBC: Armless artist 'denied entry' to UK\n",
        "BBC: Bangladesh protest clashes kill 27\n",
        "BBC: Ex-Italian PM Giulio Andreotti dies\n"}

    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        w <- headlines[randInt(0, len(headlines))]
        time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    }
}

func Feeder1(w chan string) {
    headlines := []string{
        "SKY: Deadly Virus Can 'Spread Between People'\n",
        "SKY: Ariel Castro's Brothers Brand Him 'A Monster'\n",
        "SKY: Astronaut Ends Space Mission With Bowie Song\n",
        "SKY: Chinese Artist Films Violent Street Brawl\n",
        "SKY: May Washout: Fortnight's Rainfall In One Day\n",
        "SKY: Mother's Day Shooting: CCTV Shows Suspect\n"}

    for i := 0; ; i++ {
        w <- headlines[randInt(0, len(headlines))]
        //randomTimeValue := randInt(5, 6)
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
    }
}

func Consumer(n chan string) {

    for {
        v := <-n
        fmt.Printf("Headline:\t%s", v)
    }
}

func randInt(min int, max int) int {
    return min + rand.Intn(max-min)
}
```

Both of these versions wont work on playground website.

Thank you

Comment: I'm probably not focused enough, but after third reading I still cannot figure out what's the question. Or even find it in the first place.

Comment: Apologies I forgot to make it clear, it's basically I'm getting index out of boundary exception with my array version. I'll edit the topic now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
selection := []string{}
for s := 0; s <= 3; s++ {
    selection[s] = headlines[randInt(0, len(headlines))]
}
```

`selection` is a slice of length 0. When you try to set values to indexes 0, 1 and 2 - that's causing a **runtime** error because there's no space allocated for them.

The preferred way to initialize a slice is using `make()`:

```
selection := make([]string, 3, 3)
for s := 0; s <= 3; s++ {
    selection[s] = headlines[randInt(0, len(headlines))]
}
```

The third argument to `make()` is capacity.

Another possibility is to let the runtime grow your slice implicitly by using `append()`:

```
selection := []string{}
for s := 0; s <= 3; s++ {
    selection = append(selection, headlines[randInt(0, len(headlines))])
}
```

`append()` will grow a slice as necessary.

[Link to relevant documentation](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#allocation_make)

Comment: I've tried append before and that didn't work either, I'm getting "first argument to append must be slice; have string" without the fixed size slice code. Thanks for your input

Comment: I get the idea though and I'm working to fix it. again thanks

Comment: Sorry my bad, the 3rd code block had a mistake. I've corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Your string "array" code is using slices, not arrays.
You are doing selection[q] = something, but your slice
has length 0, that should panic. Either: Make proper
slice with len != 0 or do use an array.

(I personally prefer playground code).

Comment: yea sorry for the blond moments, I just wanted to get better understanding of the communication concept first before diving into other things but apparently my issue arent channels here. thanks for your input